# Please, explain some Android Service Concepts

Tags: android, android-service

I'm just approaching Android Services, but i have many doubts. Here there are some questions.
Before starting, notice i have read those pages
[Android Services (official)](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)
[Bounded Services (official)](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)
plus sone Inner classes theory in my language. Please be patient, i'm still a bit confused.

1) First of all, a Services differentiates itself from an AsyncTask mainly because it continues to run also if the app is paused (i.e. the user is watching another app); AsyncTask is stopped in that cases. Is it ok or am i wrong?
2) A Service runs in the same thread of the activity that started it through startService().
To not affect the Activity's performances, i have to create a separate thread for that Service, for example implementing the Runnable interface. Another method is making a service that extends IntentService, which automatically provides a new thread for the service: a new thread is created on any onHandleIntent() call.

Now, let's look at my concrete problem. I need to create a Service that will be used by many Activities: his task will be to connect to the server DB every 60 seconds and check for news. If a news is found, notify there's a new news (if we are on MainActivity) or show the new news's title (if we are in the news reader). How should i code it?
I have made a MainActivity that instantiate a NewsService and immediately calls startService(). On the other side, i have the NewsService extends IntentService, that (creates a new thread when onHandleIntent is called?) and looks for new news. Is it a bad idea to use a IntentService? I realized it will be very ugly to start the service calling startService() indefinitely.
At the start of this exercize i tought it was a good solution because it automatically creates a new thread and makes Service implementation simple. But now i have some doubts (i can't know if there's a news! How can MainActivity know it? And how to get the title)

This should be done with a normal extends Thread class, that makes an infinite cicle in it's run() method, checking for news every 60 seconds and, if there's a new one, reads the title from remote DB AND update activities buttons/views. Then if the App will be closed by user, the Service will be closed too.
But the problem is that if i istantiate such class it's work will be stopped when the MainActivity is paused or stopped, and other Activities (the NewsReader in this case) cannot get any update because the new thread isn't getting news at the moment. So i need a Service.

I hope it's clear. How should i implement a solution in the right way?
Please highlight everything wrong in my text, i really need to learn :D

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have understood everything correctly.

As to your specific problem, I'd recommend the following:

- Use `AlarmManager` to schedule your service. Don't let the `Service` run when it does not have to.
- Use a `Broadcast Intent` for new news. All `Activities` will have to have an inner `BroadcastReceiver` that listens for the `Broadcast` intent of the service and reacts accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. I actually know nothing about Broadcast Intent and Broadcast Receiver: if noone give me a solution, i'll go straight on the relative Docs :D. BTW, i cannot believe i've understood everything xD

Comment: This may give you some understanding of `Broadcast`: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Comment: Also, this article has information on scheduling a Service via `AlarmManager` and on posting updates via `Broadcasts`: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: That's great. But what's the difference between making a Bound Service and using a BroadcastReceiver? Bounding a service seems something nonsense-complicated, and BroadcastReceiver seems simpler and more usable for many needs

Answer (score 0):

Services are a good approach for what you want, they are pretty good to do processes that consume few resources like keeping a daemon in background, they are also good to show notifications without an activity and keep running even if you exit the activity.

When you need to do more heavy operations in your service you can still use an `AsyncTask`, launch it, execute your operation in another thread and automatically receive the result in your main thread.

If you want to keep the service always running you can use `START_STICKY` in your Service

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags,
        final int startId) {
    // Ensure the service will restart if it dies
    return START_STICKY;
    }
```

And you can launch the service doing:

```
final Intent service = new Intent();
service.setComponent(new ComponentName(YourService.PACKAGE_NAME,
    YourService.SERVICE_FULL_NAME));

// Start the service
context.startService(service);
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1) First of all, a Services differentiates itself from an AsyncTask
>   mainly because it continues to run also if the app is paused (i.e. the
>   user is watching another app); AsyncTask is stopped in that cases. Is
>   it ok or am i wrong?

This is not correct. `AsyncTask` is a mechanism for offloading background processing into a separate thread and provides a mechanism for informing the user of progress, error and completion of that background processing. `AsyncTask` does not stop working if the app is paused. It continues to perform its processing in the background. In general, there is tight coupling between an `AsyncTask` and the `Activity` that started it.

A `Service`, on the other hand, is (generally) completely decoupled from the `Activity` that started it. A `Service` has its own lifecycle which is independent of the other activities in the app. Also, services have no UI, so they are not linked to the visual elements of the application and they provide no (direct) mechanisms for visual feedback related to progress, error or completion. This needs to programmed separately.

> 2) A Service runs in the same thread of the
>   activity that started it through startService(). To not affect the
>   Activity's performances, i have to create a separate thread for that
>   Service, for example implementing the Runnable interface. Another
>   method is making a service that extends IntentService, which
>   automatically provides a new thread for the service: a new thread is
>   created on any onHandleIntent() call.

This isn't correct either. A `Service` doesn't run on any specific thread. The **lifecycle methods** of a `Service` (`onCreate()`, `onStartCommand()`, etc.) run on the main (UI) thread, which may or may not be the same thread that called `startService()`. However, a `Service` can (and usually does) start other background threads, as many as it needs to, to perform the necessary work.

`IntentService` is a specific kind of `Service` which manages one or more worker threads that it uses to perform background processing. You send a "command" to an `IntentService` and the `IntentService` then puts your command in a queue. At some point (different implementations in different Android versions behave differently), your "command" is dequeued and processed in a background thread. `IntentService` stops itself after all the "commands" have been processed. `IntentService` is often not the best choice for a `Service` due to the way it behaves.

---

`IntentService` is definitely not what you want in your case. You should probably use `AlarmManager` and set an alarm that starts your `Service` every minute. When your `Service` starts, it should create a background thread that contacts your server and checks for news. If there is no news it can just go away. If there is new news, it can either start your `Activity` to inform the user, or it can send a broadcast `Intent` which your `Activity` will see (if it is running),or it could create a `Notification` which the user can then open whenever he wants to. You need to figure out how you want to determine when the app should stop checking the server. Maybe the user should tell you that he isn't interested anymore, or maybe the `Service` can recognize that the app isn't running anymore (or hasn't been looked at in more than X hours or whatever). There are lots of ways to do this and it depends on your requirements.